# How do I set proper orientation and resize images uploaded via PHP with Apache? I'm coming from a Windows server

Tags: php, image, apache, image-processing, image-resizing

Here is the code I had been using on my Windows server. It launch a console app that just did the resizing and moving of images for me. I've since changed my host to a shared Apache/PHP server. How can I do the following from pure PHP?

```
function image_magic($filename, $pinid)
{
    $cmdline = '"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16\\convert.exe" C:\\uploads\\'.$filename.'.jpg -resize 750x750 C:\\website\\'.$filename.'.jpg ';
    exec($cmdline);

    $cmdline = '"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16\\convert.exe" C:\\uploads\\'.$filename.'.jpg -auto-orient C:\\website\\'.$filename.'.jpg ';
    exec($cmdline);

    $cmdline = '"C:\\Program Files\\ImageMagick-6.8.7-Q16\\convert.exe" C:\\uploads\\'.$filename.'.jpg -resize 120x120 C:\\website\\'.$filename.'.jpg ';
    exec($cmdline);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://php.net/imagick ? Imagick::resizeImage, Imagick::setImageOrientation, etc.

Comment: That may do the trick. Would you happen to know what the equivalent to -auto-orient with `imagick` would be?

Comment: Are you sure your shared host doesn't have ImageMagick? Try `which convert`.

Comment: Oh I guess I didn't realize that Imagick and ImageMagick were the same things! Dumb me. I will check to see if they have it installed.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely the easier way to go. Otherwise you have to detect the exif rotation and rotate it accordingly with Imagick::rotateImage()

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good Solid class could do what you want in PHP

The first example below will load a file named picture.jpg resize it to 250 pixels wide and 400 pixels high and resave it as picture2.jpg

```
    <?php 
include('SimpleImage.php'); ///Include The Class
$image = new SimpleImage(); /// Call the class
$image->load('picture.jpg'); ///The Picture you want to Resize
$image->resize(250,400); /// height and width you want to resize image to
$image->save('picture2.jpg'); /// image output
?>
```

The Class and More Examples can be found here 
[Image Resizing Class](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/)